# Record and repeat mouse actions

Tags: windows, mouse

I am looking for a software that lets me record and save mouse movement and clicks.

The main feature I need is a random delay between the repeats, but within a preset range. For instance, repeat the recorded actions every [1,30] seconds.

I use [Mouse Controller](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mousecontroller/) but I cannot set the range of the random delays.

Update with an example of usage:

I use MouseController now in a couple of things. One of them. I have to repeat certain mouse actions every few days in a server and I want to avoid manual work. Why I need the random delay? Because I want to collect data by clicking from an autorefreshed list. If I repeat every 3 seconds, I will take the 1-6-11-16-21 etc point from the list. I want to take the randomly without any pattern. But as I said, this is only one of the reasons.

Comment: [Related question about a macro recorder for keystrokes](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14490/whats-a-good-keystroke-macro-recorder-and-replayer-on-windows)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is a general-purpose desktop automation scripting environment for Windows. It's open source.

The scripting language is *ahem* baroque. But it's ok for simple tasks, and there are quite a few snippets on the site that you can use without needing to understand all the nuances.

[Mouse Movement & Click Recorder](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/59817-mouse-movement-click-recorder/) does what it says on the tin. It records an AHK script that you can execute. You can [`Sleep`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Sleep.htm) for a [`Random`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Random.htm) time between executions if you want.

Comment: Note that Mouse Movement & Click Recorder fails to record properly on which screen the mouse was in a multi-monitor setup (at least on mine).

Answer (score 3):

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) is a script language which allow to automate the Windows's user interface, **mouse action included**.

It's a programming script language, so it´s very powerful (**your random functionnality is easily possible**) but it could be complicated for an uninitiated public. Actually a *macro recorder is provided*, very useful for learning it.

Your script can also be exported as an *exe* file.

It´s well known for the large amount of game bots created with it. Personnaly I used it for automating text copy/paste and sending it throught the network.

Comment: Thank you for your recommandation. To be frank, I tried AutoIt several years before for another project and it will be my last choice, if I won't find a freeware to work with.

Comment: I understand you @AnastasiosVentouris, this tool can be too exhaustive for certain needs. Did you try the macro recorder when you have tested it?

Comment: What I find interesting is that AutoHotkey, which is currently the top-voted and accepted answer, is rather similar to AutoIt. Yet the asker has said AutoIt would be the last resort. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the freeware [TinyTask](https://www.tinytask.net/).

It is very simple to use (record/play and save/load recordings):

[image: Screenshot]

Note that it records mouse movements/clicks (your requirement) but not keyboard usage. This can sometimes be circumvented with mouse-operated cut-n-paste.

It has no installer, you download the executable, put that somewhere and use it.

Comment: Their official website isn't working right now, but I've found a copy of TinyTask here: http://www.freewarefiles.com/TinyTask_program_50364.html